# Is there way to typify function to filter object with not null attribute on Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an entity which can be created on UI, or it can be sent by database

```
interface Task {
   id?: number | null,
   description: string,
}
```

If entity came from database, id must be present

```
type DatabaseRecord<T extends {id: number | null | undefined}> = Omit<T, 'id'> & {id: number}
```

So now i need a filter function which can help me to determine object from database, so i tried this variant but it is not working:

```
export function isInputFromDatabase<T>(input: null | undefined | T): input is DatabaseRecord<T> {
   return input !== null && input !== undefined && !!input.id;
}

...

source$: Observable<Task | null> = store.currenTask$
...
source$.pipe(filter(inputFromDatabase)).subscribe((task) => doSmthWithId(task.id))
```

So is there way to filter entity with not null/undefined id?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just intersect `T` with `{ id: number }`:

```
function isInputFromDatabase<T extends { id?: number | null | undefined }>(input: null | undefined | T): input is T & { id: number } {
   return input !== null && input !== undefined && !!input.id;
}
```

Also, you need a generic constraint on `T` so that you can use `input.id`.

[Playground (with example usage)](https://tsplay.dev/N7orRN)